# Is there a way to transfer a Launchpad layout to another machine?

Tags: macos, launchpad

If I spend time grouping apps in neat folders in Launchpad on one machine, is there a way to copy that mapping to another system without having to manually organize everything all over again ?

Answer (score 3):

It does appear to work. Copy over the existing entry in the target ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock folder with the source file. The first use of launchpad was missing the majority of the icons but logging out and back in again to the account resolved this.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this yet, but I according to [this TUAW article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150301183037/http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/21/how-to-refresh-os-x-lions-launchpad-contents/) the .db files in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock` contain all the configuration information for Launchpad.

I presume copying this folder to another machine will duplicate the configuration. Let us know if it works.

There are three ways to get to your Library folder:

-You can use the terminal to copy the files manually

-You can enter this in the terminal to "unhide" your Library folder within Finder so that you are always able to see it.
    chflags nohidden ~/Library

-Or you can simply open Finder click Go, then press the Option key (alt) to temporarily show it in the list (this is the safest option).

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was copying the name of the original .db file that I wanted to remove, (let's say ABC123) then logged out of the user account. I logged in as an administrative user and deleted the original .db file then copied over my new one and gave it the ABC123 name I'd copied from the user's original. Convoluted, and maybe someone has a better way, but that's what worked for me. There was on icon out of place when I opened LaunchPad but it was easy enough to fix and all my folders were as I'd set them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but there's [lporg](https://github.com/blacktop/lporg), a command-line utility that purports to do just this.