# Is there a programmatic way to save and re-create launchpad groups in Mojave?

Tags: backup, command-line, mojave, launchpad

I have to switch machines from time to time.  [I keep a dotfiles](https://github.com/NewAlexandria/dotfiles) that's pretty elaborate, as part of this routine.  I'd also like to make my launchpad folders be portable.

I'm fine with solution that involve the CLI, applescript, or anything that I can do reliably.

A commentor indicated I can run `find /private/var/folders -type d -name 'com.apple.dock.launchpad' 2>/dev/null`

but it yields multiple results:

```
/private/var/folders/sy/wnh38ggx3111qkdkjy2gvk940000gn/0/com.apple.dock.launchpad
/private/var/folders/xq/ynvgvft97l9_rx42cvywqx2m0000gp/0/com.apple.dock.launchpad
/private/var/folders/th/gjmmnngn4l13w0_xyxhr4y6c0000gq/0/com.apple.dock.launchpad
```

[A similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18089/37586) was asked, but that was a while ago.  In an apple forum, [someone shared the location of the core / default Dock DB](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8285610?answerId=33042793022#33042793022), but not the user-specific one.

If anyone knows how these strings are generated, it might be a viable answer.

Comment: Open **Terminal** and use the following _compound command_ to copy the **Launchpad Database** to the _current directory_, which by _default_ is you `$HOME` _directory_: `cp -aRv "$(find /private/var/folders -type d -name 'com.apple.dock.launchpad' 2>/dev/null)/db" .`

Comment: That is nifty @user3439894 but forme it returns 3 DBs, so it won't make a programmatic solution.

Comment: It only returned one for me; however, you'll have to check and see which one of those is the actual current Launchpad database.

Answer (score 2):

In true form, along the way of figuring out how to ask the questions, I seem to have found part of a hint.

[There is a folder path](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8285610?answerId=33045947022#33045947022) `/private/var/folders/` that contains a rats-nest of directories with non-human-parseable names.  Supposedly one of these contains my Launchpad's database.

If I can learn which, and how to find it programmatically, I will update the answer

---

The DB groups name + parents can be found in the DB with via

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM items i JOIN groups g ON g.item_id = i.rowid 
ORDER BY i.parent_id, i.ordering
```

The issue remains that apps are listed by a `UUID`, not name.  This suggests that they may not port well to a different computer, since a `UUID` is typically made in the local context.  However, apps registered via the app store or via Apple's dev program may have consistent UUIDs.

Comment: "Supposedly one of these contains my Launchpad's database." To find which one, make a change in Launchpad and watch what files change. If necessary, repeat the process a couple times to isolate the right location.

Comment: Yes I know that can be done manually, but it won't work for a programmatic solution